# Relative path doesnt work after include?

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I have made a config file that includes te database information (connection, and more).
The config file is called by index.php. So I have this:
index.php->calls->config.php->calls->db.php

This works, but sometimes the config.php is not called by the index.php but by for example header.php. The problem is that the relative path in the config.php to the db.php doesn't work.

How can I solve that? Should I use absolute paths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If all the files are located in the same directory, you can include it like this:

```
include __DIR__."/config.php";
```

Otherwise create a constant in your index.php page before all includes that define your application path, and use that to include your files, E.G:

in index.php:

```
 define('APP', __DIR__);
 include APP.'/config/config.php';
```

in config.php:

```
include APP.'/lib/db.php';
```